# MySQL/MariaDB: How to create index for group query with self-join inner query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, mariadb

In my MariaDB database I have this query I am hoping to speed up:

```sql
select
  move,
  color,
  count(*) as count
from
  (
    select
      b2.move,
      b2.color
    from
      game_fen_bridge b1
      inner join game_fen_bridge b2 on b1.game_id = b2.game_id
    where
      b2.ply > b1.ply
      and b2.ply < b1.ply + 10
      and b1.fen_id = 301
  ) inner_query
group by
  move,
  color;
```

It takes about 1.7 seconds, which is not great since it's needed by the UI. Also it'll get longer as the data grows if I don't do something about it. Here's the EXPLAIN:

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                         | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows  | Extra                                                     |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | b1    | ref  | game_id,game_id_2,pgf,pfg,gpf,fpg,fgp | fpg     | 9       | const                       | 78964 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | b2    | ref  | game_id,game_id_2,pgf,pfg,gpf         | game_id | 9       | danbockn_gambase.b1.game_id |    37 | Using index condition                                     |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, it has quite a few indexes to choose from. Before posting here, I tried to solve the problem by brute force by creating an index using every permutation of game_id, fen_id and ply. Nothing changes the database's insistence on scanning 78,964 rows.

Here's the table. It has about 8.4 million rows. 39,701 of them match the fen_id from the where clause, 301.

```sql
create table game_fen_bridge (
  id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  game_id bigint unsigned,
  fen_id bigint unsigned,
  move varchar(7),
  move_number tinyint unsigned,
  ply tinyint unsigned,
  color enum('w', 'b'),
  constraint foreign key (game_id) references games (game_id),
  constraint foreign key (fen_id) references fens (fen_id),
  unique(game_id, fen_id, ply),
  unique(game_id, fen_id, move_number, color)
);
```

Is there a way to speed up this query?

Updated: example data and output

```
+---------+----------+---------+-------+-------------+------+-------+
| id      | game_id  | fen_id  | move  | move_number | ply  | color |
+---------+----------+---------+-------+-------------+------+-------+
| 6483612 |  9866652 |     301 | d4    |           1 |    1 | w     |
| 6483613 |  9866652 |     302 | d5    |           1 |    2 | b     |
| 6483616 |  9866652 |    1853 | Nf3   |           3 |    5 | w     |
| 6483614 |  9866652 |    3101 | Bf4   |           2 |    3 | w     |
| 6483615 |  9866652 |   44813 | e6    |           2 |    4 | b     |
| 6483617 |  9866652 |  243743 | c5    |           3 |    6 | b     |
| 6483618 |  9866652 |  243744 | e3    |           4 |    7 | w     |
| 6483619 |  9866652 |  243745 | Nc6   |           4 |    8 | b     |
| 6483620 |  9866652 | 2103234 | Bb5   |           5 |    9 | w     |
| 6483621 |  9866652 | 2103235 | Bd7   |           5 |   10 | b     |
| 6483622 |  9866652 | 5444081 | c3    |           6 |   11 | w     |
| 6483623 |  9866652 | 5444082 | f5    |           6 |   12 | b     |
| 6483624 |  9866652 | 5444083 | Bxc6  |           7 |   13 | w     |
| 6483625 |  9866652 | 5444084 | Bxc6  |           7 |   14 | b     |
| 6483626 |  9866652 | 5444085 | O-O   |           8 |   15 | w     |
| 6483627 |  9866652 | 5444086 | Nf6   |           8 |   16 | b     |
| 6483628 |  9866652 | 5444087 | Ng5   |           9 |   17 | w     |
| 6483629 |  9866652 | 5444088 | Bd7   |           9 |   18 | b     |
| 6483630 |  9866652 | 5444089 | dxc5  |          10 |   19 | w     |
| 6483631 |  9866652 | 5444090 | Bxc5  |          10 |   20 | b     |
| 6483632 |  9866652 | 5444091 | Be5   |          11 |   21 | w     |
| 6483633 |  9866652 | 5444092 | O-O   |          11 |   22 | b     |
| 6483634 |  9866652 | 5444093 | Bxf6  |          12 |   23 | w     |
| 6483635 |  9866652 | 5444094 | Qxf6  |          12 |   24 | b     |
| 6483636 |  9866652 | 5444095 | Qh5   |          13 |   25 | w     |
| 6483637 |  9866652 | 5444096 | h6    |          13 |   26 | b     |
| 6483638 |  9866652 | 5444097 | Nh3   |          14 |   27 | w     |
| 6483639 |  9866652 | 5444098 | g5    |          14 |   28 | b     |
| 6483640 |  9866652 | 5444099 | b4    |          15 |   29 | w     |
| 6483641 |  9866652 | 5444100 | Bxb4  |          15 |   30 | b     |
| 6483642 |  9866652 | 5444101 | Rc1   |          16 |   31 | w     |
| 6483643 |  9866652 | 5444102 | Rac8  |          16 |   32 | b     |
| 6483644 |  9866652 | 5444103 | a3    |          17 |   33 | w     |
| 6483645 |  9866652 | 5444104 | Bxc3  |          17 |   34 | b     |
| 6483646 |  9866652 | 5444105 | Nxc3  |          18 |   35 | w     |
| 6483647 |  9866652 | 5444106 | Rxc3  |          18 |   36 | b     |
| 6483648 |  9866652 | 5444107 | Rab1  |          19 |   37 | w     |
| 6483649 |  9866652 | 5444108 | Rfc8  |          19 |   38 | b     |
| 6483650 |  9866652 | 5444109 | Rd1   |          20 |   39 | w     |
| 6483651 |  9866652 | 5444110 | Ba4   |          20 |   40 | b     |
| 6483652 |  9866652 | 5444111 | Rf1   |          21 |   41 | w     |
| 6483653 |  9866652 | 5444112 | b5    |          21 |   42 | b     |
| 6483654 |  9866652 | 5444113 | f4    |          22 |   43 | w     |
| 6483655 |  9866652 | 5444114 | g4    |          22 |   44 | b     |
| 6483656 |  9866652 | 5444115 | Nf2   |          23 |   45 | w     |
| 6483657 |  9866652 | 5444116 | Rxe3  |          23 |   46 | b     |
| 6483658 |  9866652 | 5444117 | g3    |          24 |   47 | w     |
| 6483659 |  9866652 | 5444118 | b4    |          24 |   48 | b     |
| 6483660 |  9866652 | 5444119 | Rxb4  |          25 |   49 | w     |
| 6483661 |  9866652 | 5444120 | Be8   |          25 |   50 | b     |
| 6483662 |  9866652 | 5444121 | Qh4   |          26 |   51 | w     |
| 6483663 |  9866652 | 5444122 | Qxh4  |          26 |   52 | b     |
| 6483664 |  9866652 | 5444123 | gxh4  |          27 |   53 | w     |
| 6483665 |  9866652 | 5444124 | Rc4   |          27 |   54 | b     |
| 6483666 |  9866652 | 5444125 | Rb8   |          28 |   55 | w     |
| 6483667 |  9866652 | 5444126 | Kf7   |          28 |   56 | b     |
| 6483668 |  9866652 | 5444127 | Rd1   |          29 |   57 | w     |
| 6483669 |  9866652 | 5444128 | Rxf4  |          29 |   58 | b     |
| 6483670 |  9866652 | 5444129 | Nd3   |          30 |   59 | w     |
| 6483671 |  9866652 | 5444130 | Rff3  |          30 |   60 | b     |
| 6483672 |  9866652 | 5444131 | Rb7+  |          31 |   61 | w     |
| 6483673 |  9866652 | 5444132 | Kf6   |          31 |   62 | b     |
| 6483674 |  9866652 | 5444133 | Nc5   |          32 |   63 | w     |
| 6483675 |  9866652 | 5444134 | Rxa3  |          32 |   64 | b     |
| 6483676 |  9866652 | 5444135 | Re1   |          33 |   65 | w     |
| 6483677 |  9866652 | 5444136 | e5    |          33 |   66 | b     |
| 6483678 |  9866652 | 5444137 | Rb8   |          34 |   67 | w     |
| 6483679 |  9866652 | 5444138 | Bc6   |          34 |   68 | b     |
| 6483680 |  9866652 | 5444139 | Rc8   |          35 |   69 | w     |
| 6483681 |  9866652 | 5444140 | Bb5   |          35 |   70 | b     |
| 6483218 | 10757193 |     301 | d4    |           1 |    1 | w     |
| 6483219 | 10757193 |     395 | Nf6   |           1 |    2 | b     |
| 6483220 | 10757193 |     396 | c4    |           2 |    3 | w     |
| 6483221 | 10757193 |     592 | e6    |           2 |    4 | b     |
| 6483222 | 10757193 |   23786 | Nf3   |           3 |    5 | w     |
| 6483223 | 10757193 |   29571 | b6    |           3 |    6 | b     |
| 6483224 | 10757193 |   29572 | g3    |           4 |    7 | w     |
| 6483228 | 10757193 |   49264 | O-O   |           6 |   11 | w     |
| 6483229 | 10757193 |   49265 | O-O   |           6 |   12 | b     |
| 6483230 | 10757193 |   49266 | Nc3   |           7 |   13 | w     |
| 6483231 | 10757193 |   49267 | Ne4   |           7 |   14 | b     |
| 6483225 | 10757193 |   51255 | Bb7   |           4 |    8 | b     |
| 6483226 | 10757193 |   51256 | Bg2   |           5 |    9 | w     |
| 6483227 | 10757193 |  117266 | Be7   |           5 |   10 | b     |
| 6483232 | 10757193 |  259277 | Qc2   |           8 |   15 | w     |
| 6483233 | 10757193 |  259278 | Nxc3  |           8 |   16 | b     |
| 6483234 | 10757193 |  259279 | Qxc3  |           9 |   17 | w     |
| 6483235 | 10757193 | 1441865 | c5    |           9 |   18 | b     |
| 6483236 | 10757193 | 5443779 | b3    |          10 |   19 | w     |
| 6483237 | 10757193 | 5443780 | Bf6   |          10 |   20 | b     |
| 6483238 | 10757193 | 5443781 | Bb2   |          11 |   21 | w     |
| 6483239 | 10757193 | 5443782 | d6    |          11 |   22 | b     |
| 6483240 | 10757193 | 5443783 | e3    |          12 |   23 | w     |
| 6483241 | 10757193 | 5443784 | Nd7   |          12 |   24 | b     |
| 6483242 | 10757193 | 5443785 | Rad1  |          13 |   25 | w     |
| 6483243 | 10757193 | 5443786 | Qc7   |          13 |   26 | b     |
| 6483244 | 10757193 | 5443787 | Rd2   |          14 |   27 | w     |
| 6483245 | 10757193 | 5443788 | Rac8  |          14 |   28 | b     |
| 6483246 | 10757193 | 5443789 | Rfd1  |          15 |   29 | w     |
| 6483247 | 10757193 | 5443790 | cxd4  |          15 |   30 | b     |
| 6483248 | 10757193 | 5443791 | Nxd4  |          16 |   31 | w     |
| 6483249 | 10757193 | 5443792 | Bxg2  |          16 |   32 | b     |
| 6483250 | 10757193 | 5443793 | Kxg2  |          17 |   33 | w     |
| 6483251 | 10757193 | 5443794 | b5    |          17 |   34 | b     |
| 6483252 | 10757193 | 5443795 | Qb4   |          18 |   35 | w     |
| 6483253 | 10757193 | 5443796 | bxc4  |          18 |   36 | b     |
| 6483254 | 10757193 | 5443797 | Nb5   |          19 |   37 | w     |
| 6483255 | 10757193 | 5443798 | Qb7+  |          19 |   38 | b     |
| 6483256 | 10757193 | 5443799 | f3    |          20 |   39 | w     |
| 6483257 | 10757193 | 5443800 | Bxb2  |          20 |   40 | b     |
| 6483258 | 10757193 | 5443801 | Rxb2  |          21 |   41 | w     |
| 6483259 | 10757193 | 5443802 | Ne5   |          21 |   42 | b     |
| 6483260 | 10757193 | 5443803 | e4    |          22 |   43 | w     |
| 6483261 | 10757193 | 5443804 | Nd3   |          22 |   44 | b     |
| 4665951 | 13090397 |     301 | d4    |           1 |    1 | w     |
| 4665952 | 13090397 |     395 | Nf6   |           1 |    2 | b     |
| 4665953 | 13090397 |     901 | Nf3   |           2 |    3 | w     |
| 4665954 | 13090397 |    3041 | e6    |           2 |    4 | b     |
| 4665956 | 13090397 |   52873 | d5    |           3 |    6 | b     |
| 4665955 | 13090397 |   76756 | e3    |           3 |    5 | w     |
| 4665957 | 13090397 | 3944440 | Ne5   |           4 |    7 | w     |
| 4665958 | 13090397 | 3944441 | Nbd7  |           4 |    8 | b     |
| 4665959 | 13090397 | 3944442 | f4    |           5 |    9 | w     |
| 4665960 | 13090397 | 3944443 | Be7   |           5 |   10 | b     |
| 4665961 | 13090397 | 3944444 | Bd3   |           6 |   11 | w     |
| 4665962 | 13090397 | 3944445 | O-O   |           6 |   12 | b     |
| 4665963 | 13090397 | 3944446 | O-O   |           7 |   13 | w     |
| 4665964 | 13090397 | 3944447 | c5    |           7 |   14 | b     |
| 4665965 | 13090397 | 3944448 | c3    |           8 |   15 | w     |
| 4665966 | 13090397 | 3944449 | Qc7   |           8 |   16 | b     |
| 4665967 | 13090397 | 3944450 | Qf3   |           9 |   17 | w     |
| 4665968 | 13090397 | 3944451 | b6    |           9 |   18 | b     |
| 4665969 | 13090397 | 3944452 | Nd2   |          10 |   19 | w     |
| 4665970 | 13090397 | 3944453 | Bb7   |          10 |   20 | b     |
| 4665971 | 13090397 | 3944454 | Rf2   |          11 |   21 | w     |
| 4665972 | 13090397 | 3944455 | g6    |          11 |   22 | b     |
| 4665973 | 13090397 | 3944456 | Qe2   |          12 |   23 | w     |
| 4665974 | 13090397 | 3944457 | Ne4   |          12 |   24 | b     |
| 4665975 | 13090397 | 3944458 | Rf3   |          13 |   25 | w     |
| 4665976 | 13090397 | 3944459 | Ndf6  |          13 |   26 | b     |
| 4665977 | 13090397 | 3944460 | Rh3   |          14 |   27 | w     |
| 4665978 | 13090397 | 3944461 | h5    |          14 |   28 | b     |
| 4665979 | 13090397 | 3944462 | Ndf3  |          15 |   29 | w     |
| 4665980 | 13090397 | 3944463 | Kg7   |          15 |   30 | b     |
| 4665981 | 13090397 | 3944464 | Bd2   |          16 |   31 | w     |
| 4665982 | 13090397 | 3944465 | Ng4   |          16 |   32 | b     |
| 4665983 | 13090397 | 3944466 | Bxe4  |          17 |   33 | w     |
| 4665984 | 13090397 | 3944467 | dxe4  |          17 |   34 | b     |
| 4665985 | 13090397 | 3944468 | Nh4   |          18 |   35 | w     |
| 4665986 | 13090397 | 3944469 | Nxe5  |          18 |   36 | b     |
| 4665987 | 13090397 | 3944470 | fxe5  |          19 |   37 | w     |
| 4665988 | 13090397 | 3944471 | Bxh4  |          19 |   38 | b     |
| 4665989 | 13090397 | 3944472 | Rxh4  |          20 |   39 | w     |
| 4665990 | 13090397 | 3944473 | Qe7   |          20 |   40 | b     |
| 4665991 | 13090397 | 3944474 | Rh3   |          21 |   41 | w     |
| 4665992 | 13090397 | 3944475 | f6    |          21 |   42 | b     |
| 4665993 | 13090397 | 3944476 | Rg3   |          22 |   43 | w     |
| 4665994 | 13090397 | 3944477 | Kh6   |          22 |   44 | b     |
| 4665995 | 13090397 | 3944478 | Rf1   |          23 |   45 | w     |
| 4665996 | 13090397 | 3944479 | fxe5  |          23 |   46 | b     |
| 4665997 | 13090397 | 3944480 | Rf4   |          24 |   47 | w     |
| 4665998 | 13090397 | 3944481 | exf4  |          24 |   48 | b     |
| 4665999 | 13090397 | 3944482 | exf4  |          25 |   49 | w     |
| 4666000 | 13090397 | 3944483 | Rf5   |          25 |   50 | b     |
| 4666001 | 13090397 | 3944484 | Rh3   |          26 |   51 | w     |
| 4666002 | 13090397 | 3944485 | Kg7   |          26 |   52 | b     |
| 4666003 | 13090397 | 3944486 | g4    |          27 |   53 | w     |
| 4666004 | 13090397 | 3944487 | hxg4  |          27 |   54 | b     |
| 4666005 | 13090397 | 3944488 | Qxg4  |          28 |   55 | w     |
| 4666006 | 13090397 | 3944489 | Rh8   |          28 |   56 | b     |
| 4666007 | 13090397 | 3944490 | Rg3   |          29 |   57 | w     |
| 4666008 | 13090397 | 3944491 | Rh6   |          29 |   58 | b     |
| 4666009 | 13090397 | 3944492 | Rh3   |          30 |   59 | w     |
| 4666010 | 13090397 | 3944493 | Rxh3  |          30 |   60 | b     |
| 4666011 | 13090397 | 3944494 | Qxh3  |          31 |   61 | w     |
| 4666012 | 13090397 | 3944495 | Qf8   |          31 |   62 | b     |
| 4666013 | 13090397 | 3944496 | Qg4   |          32 |   63 | w     |
| 4666014 | 13090397 | 3944497 | Qh8   |          32 |   64 | b     |
| 4666015 | 13090397 | 3944498 | dxc5  |          33 |   65 | w     |
| 4666016 | 13090397 | 3944499 | Qh5   |          33 |   66 | b     |
| 4666017 | 13090397 | 3944500 | h3    |          34 |   67 | w     |
| 4666018 | 13090397 | 3944501 | Qxg4+ |          34 |   68 | b     |
| 4666019 | 13090397 | 3944502 | hxg4  |          35 |   69 | w     |
| 4666020 | 13090397 | 3944503 | Rxc5  |          35 |   70 | b     |
| 4666021 | 13090397 | 3944504 | Kf2   |          36 |   71 | w     |
| 4666022 | 13090397 | 3944505 | Kf6   |          36 |   72 | b     |
| 4666023 | 13090397 | 3944506 | Be3   |          37 |   73 | w     |
| 4666024 | 13090397 | 3944507 | Rd5   |          37 |   74 | b     |
| 4666025 | 13090397 | 3944508 | Bd4+  |          38 |   75 | w     |
| 4666026 | 13090397 | 3944509 | Rxd4  |          38 |   76 | b     |
| 4666027 | 13090397 | 3944510 | cxd4  |          39 |   77 | w     |
| 4666028 | 13090397 | 3944511 | g5    |          39 |   78 | b     |
| 4666029 | 13090397 | 3944512 | Ke3   |          40 |   79 | w     |
| 4666030 | 13090397 | 3944513 | Bd5   |          40 |   80 | b     |
| 4666031 | 13090397 | 3944514 | a3    |          41 |   81 | w     |
| 4666032 | 13090397 | 3944515 | gxf4+ |          41 |   82 | b     |
| 4666033 | 13090397 | 3944516 | Kxf4  |          42 |   83 | w     |
| 4666034 | 13090397 | 3944517 | Kg6   |          42 |   84 | b     |
| 4666035 | 13090397 | 3944518 | b4    |          43 |   85 | w     |
| 4666036 | 13090397 | 3944519 | b5    |          43 |   86 | b     |
| 4666037 | 13090397 | 3944520 | g5    |          44 |   87 | w     |
| 4666038 | 13090397 | 3944521 | Kh5   |          44 |   88 | b     |
+---------+----------+---------+-------+-------------+------+-------+
```

```
+------+-------+-------+
| move | color | count |
+------+-------+-------+
| b6   | b     |     1 |
| Bb5  | w     |     1 |
| Bb7  | b     |     1 |
| Bd7  | b     |     1 |
| Be7  | b     |     2 |
| Bf4  | w     |     1 |
| Bg2  | w     |     1 |
| c4   | w     |     1 |
| c5   | b     |     1 |
| d5   | b     |     2 |
| e3   | w     |     2 |
| e6   | b     |     3 |
| f4   | w     |     1 |
| g3   | w     |     1 |
| Nbd7 | b     |     1 |
| Nc6  | b     |     1 |
| Ne5  | w     |     1 |
| Nf3  | w     |     3 |
| Nf6  | b     |     2 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: The only useful index is (game_id,ply,fen_id), or some permutation thereof, but this has a cardinality of 1, so I guess there's not much you can do (although the super query is redundant)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like less typing...

```
select
  b2.move,
  b2.color
 , count(*) total
from
  game_fen_bridge b1
  inner join game_fen_bridge b2 on b1.game_id = b2.game_id
where
  b2.ply > b1.ply
  and b2.ply < b1.ply + 10
  and b1.fen_id = 301
group by move, color;
```

Comment: Thank you; that will help clean up the code. Unfortunately it seems the database was already optimizing away my bad code, and it's still scanning 78,964 rows with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subquery to express this:

```
select b2.move, b2.color, count(*) as total
from game_fen_bridge b1 join
     game_fen_bridge b2
     on b1.game_id = b2.game_id
where b2.ply > b1.ply and
      b2.ply < b1.ply + 10 and
      b1.fen_id = 301
group by move, color;
```

For this query, you want an index on `game_fen_bridge(game_id, fen_id, ply)`.

That said, it is quite possible that you could express the logic using window functions.  It is rather hard to say without sample data, desired results and a clear explanation of the logic, but perhaps:

```
select gfb.*,
       sum( gen_id = 301 ) over (partition by game_id order by ply range between 1 following and 9 following)
from game_fen_bridge gfb
```

Comment: I have that index already and the database is not using it.

Comment: It's a database of chess games and the question being asked is: in this given position (fen), in how many games does each possible move appear in the next 10 moves? There's one row in game_fen_bridge for each move of each game.

Comment: To clarify my comment about the database is not using that index: it is using a different permutation of game_id, fen_id and ply; I created indexes for all permutations. You can see it in the EXPLAIN output.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do

```
PRIMARY KEY(fen_id, ply, game_id)  -- deliberate reangement
INDEX(ply, game_id, color, move)   -- to "cover" the join
unique(game_id, fen_id, move_number, color)  -- unchanged
```

You understand that you are checking for 9 plies, not 10?

The subquery ("derived table") must produce all the rows.  Then the outer query must sort and count.  The GROUP BY is done one of 3 ways: with a disk temp table (unlikely), with an in-RAM temp table, or via an in-memory hash (without sorting).

Comment: Remove what? And yeah I know it's 9 plies, it'll probably change later.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't perform any better. The b1 row of the EXPLAIN shows that it's using the new primary key but still scanning about the same number of rows (`Using where` is gone from the Extra column). The query takes about the same amount of time.